# DATEADD function is not bringing the correct data SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a float datatype that is actually a date. I need to use it in the condition to obtain the data for the last 10 minutes.
I used `CAST` to convert from float to datetime. and then `DATEADD` to collect the last 10 minutes data but its not working.

```
select  CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME) as StartTime
        ,CAST(endtime AS DATETIME) as EndTime
from    BIORADFM_TASK_AUDIT
where   CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(minute, 10, GETDATE());

Result:

StartTime                EndTime
-----------------------  -----------------------
2017-10-12 16:57:06.997  2017-10-12 16:57:06.997
2017-10-12 06:06:59.997  2017-10-12 06:06:59.997
2017-10-12 06:06:47.997  2017-10-12 06:06:47.997
2017-10-11 16:04:53.000  2017-10-11 16:04:53.000
```

It´s showing data for the next two days, instead of the last 10 minutes starting from getdate.

```
Table Structure:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BIORADFM_TASK_AUDIT](
[STRGUID] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
[ACTIVITYUSERID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ACTIVITYSESSIONID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ACTIVITYCODE] [int] NOT NULL,
[SERVERNAME] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
[APPNAME] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[STARTTIME] [float] NOT NULL,
[ENDTIME] [float] NOT NULL,
[STRDESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[STRMODULENAME] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_BIORADFM_TASK_AUDIT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Sample Data:

```
StartTime           Endtime
43020.2549421296    43020.2549421296
43020.2550810185    43020.2550810185
43020.6342939815    43020.6342939815
43020.2548032407    43020.2548032407
43020.2548263889    43020.2548263889
43020.2549421296    43020.2549421296
43020.2549305556    43020.2549305556
43020.2549421296    43020.2549421296
43019.2549189815    43019.2549189815
```

Comment: A few sidenotes....https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3 https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: What do you mean that "these dates are float types"? Can you please provide the table structures, this should be in the form of "CREATE TABLE..." And also some sample data in the form of "INSERT INTO...".

Comment: @SeanLange Question is updated with table structure. This table is pre-defined by an application, we cannot insert data here.

Comment: I think you missed the point. We want the table structure and some sample data so we have something to work with. Especially in this case because floats are NOT dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want rows with an start time situated *only* in the last 10 minutes you have to filter by range, for example with `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME) AS StartTime, CAST(endtime AS DATETIME) AS EndTime
FROM BIORADFM_TASK_AUDIT
WHERE CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME) BETWEEN DATEADD(minute,-10,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `datediff()`.  It counts the number of "time boundaries" between two date/times.

Instead, use date arithmetic:

```
WHERE A.ActivityUserID = B.lUserID and 
      CAST(A.StartTime AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(minute, -10, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I updated the query but it´s still retrieving the wrong data (should bring Oct 9, but is bringing Oct 10 and 11)

Comment: @Kyana.cs . . . "instead of the last 10 minutes starting from getdate."  Why would it bring in data from multiple days?

Comment: Not sure. I updated the question with more information. The date columns are defined as float instead of datetime. And I think that´s the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess since we have nothing to work with. It would be a good idea to store datetime data as datetime instead of a strings so you don't have to constantly convert your data to the right datatype.

```
SELECT A.strGUID
    , u.sUserName
    , A.ServerName
    , A.AppName
    , A.ActivityCode
    , CAST(A.StartTime AS DATETIME) as StartTime
    , CAST(A.endtime AS DATETIME) as EndTime
    , A.strModuleName
    , A.strDescription
    , GETDATE()
FROM INTRAWPROD_TASK_AUDIT A
join HSV_ACTIVITY_USERS u on A.ActivityUserID = u.lUserID 
where convert(datetime, a.StartTime) >= convert(datetime, dateadd(minute, -10, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: You´re right Sean, but this data type was already declare like that, and I have to work with it.

Comment: I feel your pain. We don't always get to make things right. Does this query work for you?

Comment: No, it doesn´t. Keeps showing Oct 10 and 11 instead of Oct 9. I´m thinking if it´s not because that datetime field. Maybe it´s not reading it correctly

Comment: Well I am done playing the guessing game. If you still need help you need to provide table definitions and sample data that represents the problem. Here is a great example. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/